# how to count the number of associations for each gene

Tags: r

I have an output file from `eqtl` analysis with `MatrixEQTL`:

```
SNP gene    beta    t-stat  p-value FDR
ch01_76563780   GW_06g072920    0.049942008791647   932.306067766817    2.2250738585072e-308    1.60416093688267e-302
ch02_36905357   GW_06g072920    -0.049942008791647  -932.306067766817   2.2250738585072e-308    1.60416093688267e-302
ch07_69573723   GW_06g072920    0.049942008791647   932.306067766817    2.2250738585072e-308    1.60416093688267e-302
ch01_87880392   GW_06g072920    0.0499413219745195  923.819795644165    2.2250738585072e-308    1.60416093688267e-302
```

I am trying to count associations per gene to get the significant genes for a summary. I will appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: hi user 1567654, how do you define associations? If there is a formula to follow then perform that operation on the data grouped by 'gene'. e.g. data %>% dplyr::group_by(gene) %>% dplyr::summarize(result = your_association_formula). good luck.

Comment: Hi @Jagge, thank you! Each row represents an association here. I want to see how many SNP (column 1) are in the output for each gene. For eaxmple, gene GW_06g072920 has 4 SNPs associated in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so associations is essentially the number of rows a particular gene is present in the data?
then it is simple to group by the gene and count the numbers

```
library(magrittr)
eqtl %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(gene) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Associations = dplyr::n())

# here is a small example with a toy df
tibble::tibble(SNPS = 1:4, Gene = "testgene") %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Gene) %>% 
  dplyr:::summarise(Associations = dplyr::n())
```

will this work, let me know!

good luck :)

Comment: It worked, thank you! I have a follow up question though. I want to use a for loop to define a window (say 10000 bp each direction) to count any SNP. So that is there is a SNP, then I do not count any other SNP around 10000 bp in each direction for summary purposes. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: glad it worked, please mark the answer as correct, so that others can quickly glance the page and know that the thing is answered (also I get the sweet points), you might be best helped by posting a new question. But maybe do something like: for(i in 1:(nrow(eqt1)-10000)){ df_tmp <- eqt[i:i+9999,] (and then do some calculation on the subset in the dataframe df_tmp) }. good luck :)

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestion or post another question. Can you please help me plot the results into a bar graph like gene on x-axis and number of associations on y-axis.